# Запись в PHP файл

Tags: php

Создал в php файл php. Хочу в него записать копировании команды и теги из другого файла. Например:

```
$text = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
@import "/css/style.css"; /*импорт файла стилей*/
</style>".......;
```

выдает ошибку. Можете помочь?

Comment: Надо приводить текст ошибки в вопросе ..

Answer (score 1):

Замени `"` на `'` внутри переменной.

Comment: Спасибо. Почти помогло. Сейчас не нравится эта строка внутри текста: <? require_once('C:/OpenServer/domains/msg/users/test/count_test.php'); ?>

Comment: Попробуйте вынести в отдельный файл все что находится в переменной и уже подключать этот файл

Comment: Как подключить файл? И наверно текстовый?

Comment: include, а насчет формата не уверен, наверно .php

Comment: Кроме того что строка "не нравится", может там ещё какой-нибудь текст ошибки появляется?

Comment: а также хочу добавить переменную $b:

$b = "'";
$a = ' $f_name <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        @import "/css/style.css"; /*импорт файла стилей*/
    </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <p><a href="http://msg/"><img src="../../../images/ezgif.com-crop.gif" width="50" height="50" border="0" alt="Пример"></a></p>
    <?php
require_once( $b C:/OpenServer/domains/msg/users/test/count_test.php $b);
    ?>';